# Normalizing redux state for REST API

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, web-services, redux

Consider the following Reddit inspired schema

[image]

I'm developing admin GUI for managing users, posts and comments (faking the actual domain here). React application has distinct routes (navigation tabs):

- **Users** to list users with their posts and comments
- **Posts** to list posts with their comments (both including originating user)

Both routes also allows editing of the listed entities.

I have defined following REST endpoints

```
/users
/users/{id}/posts
/users/{id}/
/posts
/posts/{id}/comments
```

How should I shape the Redux state in this case? Should I

A) Simply keep different entity types in their own subtree grouped by id? In that case retrieving all posts or retrieving posts for users would actually operate on the same subtree. React component would filter this subtree to retrieve it's props as it fits.

B) Shape the tree more fine grained to usage with routes? For example, group posts route posts by id and users route posts by user id? This solution would result in some redundant duplication, until extra effort is used to keep things normalized.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the app you're building. Did you go over the https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape?

From the API endpoints it looks like posts and users are pretty separated, while comments are live in the context of post. If this is true this redux state can be a good start:

```
{
  entities: {
    posts: {
      [postId1]: [
        // comments
      ],
      ...
    },
    users: {
      [userId]: {
        posts: [postId1, postId2, ...]
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  ui: {
    screen1: {
      fetchedPosts: [postId1, postId2],
      fetchedUsers: [userId10, userId11]
    }
  }
}
```

The `entities` is used as a local database of the fetched data, while the `ui` holds the ids of the entities to render for specific components. When the component doing a fetch, the response data is stored in the relevant entity, while the ids is also stored in the component's redux state. Then in the component's render method you match between the two.

Using this pattern you have a single source of truth, can share entities between components, do pagination, persist data. This is a good [example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) for implementation details